# No Python module despite installing it

Tags: python, module, pip

I've installed `xxhash` module with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install xxhash
```

But when I execute:

```
pydoc modules
```

I get a list of available modules in which there's no `xxhash`.

And when I run in terminal a GUI program it gives me an error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pogom.search import search_overseer_thread, fake_search_loop
  File "/SOME_PATH/resources/app/map/pogom/search.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pgoapi import PGoApi
  File "/SOME_PATH/resources/app/map/pogom/pgoapi/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>

Python:     from .pgoapi import PGoApi
  File "/SOME_PATH/resources/app/map/pogom/pgoapi/pgoapi.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .rpc_api import RpcApi
  File "/SOME_PATH/resources/app/map/pogom/pgoapi/rpc_api.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .utilities import to_camel_case, get_time, get_format_time_diff, Rand48, long_to_bytes, generateLocation1, generateLocation2, generateRequestHash, f2i
  File "/SOME_PATH/resources/app/map/pogom/pgoapi/utilities.py", line 37, in <module>
    import xxhash
ImportError: No module named xxhash
```

BTW, the 2 first commands worked with no error and when I rerun them it says that these modules are already installed and up to date.

Comment: And on the Python cmd prompt, what does `>>> import xxhash` give? Id 'say that is more telling than using `./runserver.py`.

Comment: Probably, `pip` uses a different `python` executable than you are using in your program. Check the first line of `./runserver.py`, and use *that* Python executable to install `xxhash` with, for example with `/whatever/full/path/python -m pip install xxhash`.

Comment: `>>> import xxhash` also returned the error `ImportError: No module named xxhash`. I ran your last command with /usr/bin/python and it appeared that I don't have pip installed. The problem was that I had python3-pip and not python-pip. Then I installed xxhash with your command and it worked. Thanks! Please copy your comment to an answer to I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: You need Python.h to build xxhash. apt-get install python-dev on Ubuntu, yum install python-devel on CentOS/Fedora